# LED Hissing issue with circuits

Tags: led, pcb-design, esp8266, led-strip, nodemcu

I have just recently designed and manufactured my very first PCB with the goal of it being a dedicated circuit to my project. I developed an ESP8266 WiFi Mood Light, but the problems I currently face with VERSION 1 is that is makes a sort of hissing noise when I change colors via Blynk, and the transistors used in the project get very hot very fast. I know this has something to do with the current throughout the circuit being to high, but I don't know how to go about it.

I am open to further suggestions as well.[image: PCB Schematic]

Thanks

UPDATE: Thanks for the telling me the solution to the problem, but unfortunately after implementing it on a breadboard, the circuit didn't the way I wanted it too. After swapping the emitter with the collector, the RGB led strip would not change color via Blynk. I have no idea how to fix it now. (LED strip uses 3 Amps)

[image: The revised transistor position[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGRmY.jpg)
[[image: The LED strip state with the new transistor position]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrITo.jpg)

UPDATE 2: I have changed the BJT type transistors to MOSFETS now. The system works without overheating, however the hissing noise still persists, I have researched about the idea of a low pass RC filter, but I am not sure if it would be suitable.

[image: Revised circuit with MOSFETS]

UPDATE 3: Thank you all for helping me troubleshoot this circuit. It now works without overheating, and hissing. It turns out the hissing was related to the MP1584EN, so I changed it.

[image: The finished fully working circuit]

Comment: The transistors are connected improperly...the emitters should be connected to ground and the collectors connected to the LEDs. How much current are you trying to pass through each transistor?

Comment: Indeed you're using the transistors "upside down" and then instead of the usual current amplification of say 100 you get the "reverse mode" current amplification which is much less like 5 or 10 if you're lucky. Then a voltage will drop across the NPNs (as they're not in saturation) which will make them run hot. Also the MP1584 does not appear to be connected correctly. The node between Vin- and C1 should be grounded but isn't? Maybe it is through the module. That's not a nice way to do/draw that.

Comment: Is the 1mF capacitor supposed to represent your power supply?

Comment: PCB design is fun and can be rewarding for sure, but I'm not sure how you would salvage/repair this PCBs to make it work. Check out [solderless breadboards](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/prototyping-fabrication-products/solderless-breadboards/638) - You can test and debug most circuits without the time and money investment of a fab'd PCB. Best of luck on your next version!

Comment: You may be dragging your power supply out of regulation due to a lack of series resistor on the LEDs, which could be causing the power supply to make noise.

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone, I have made the changes on a breadboard, however the circuit still seems to have the same problems; it still gets very hot, and this time the transistor doesn't seem to be doing its job. I have attached pictures above.

Comment: If your problem (as stated in your "UPDATE 2") is the hissing noise, then you must do more diagnosis about that e.g. where *exactly* is the noise coming from? From the NodeMCU, or the switching MOSFETs, or (I expect most likely) from that pre-built MP1584 buck converter module, which you haven't told us anything about :-) If you confirm that is the source, then (a) reverse engineer its schematic, (b) vary how you use it and see how that changes the noise (e.g. reduce current by using only 1 LED; try parallel wires to reduce eff wiring resistance etc.). (c) Try different buck regulator. etc.

Comment: I started reading, and when I got to the mention of V1, I looked down at the schematic to see what it is, but it's not there. What the ...?  Not gonna waste more time here.  Closing, and -1 for jerking us around.

Comment: @OlinLathrop My guess is that V1 means version 1, not a component.

Comment: @Jash: LoL.  That hadn't occurred to me at all.  I suppose the OP might have meant that.  Even if so *unclear* still stands.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Oh, I completely agree. :)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany These LED strips are designed for constant voltage operation and have appropriate resistors and series wiring for that.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Hi, I have made the text more obvious. It now says "VERSION 1" instead of "V1".

Answer (score 3):

All your output transistors are wired the wrong way round (red box): -

[image]

Neither are you using current limiting resistors in series with R, G and B pins.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your other question where you say the strip uses 3 amps:

1 amp per 2n2222 is too much for the to-92 package 2n2222. Max collector emitter current for it is 800mA or 0.8A. Find a higher current transistor or use a logic level mosfet. The hissing may be related to the over driven transistor.

Comment: Hi Passerby, do you happen to have any suggestions for an appropriate transistor I could use in this circuit? And would I require a pull down resistor if I use a logic level MOSFET?